# How can I add Integer using '##' in C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define DEF6 625
#define DEF6 625
#define DEF(n) DEF##n

void main(){
    printf("%d\n", DEF(6));
}
```

This code works.
but

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define DEF6 625
#define DEF(n) DEF##n

void main(){
    int a=6;
    printf("%d\n", DEF(a));
}
```

This code does not work.
Error result is like this

> Line 8: error: 'DEFa' undeclared (first use in this function)
>       Line 8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>       Line 8: error: for each function it appears in.)

So how can I add Integer type variable to `#define` using `##`?

Comment: `##` is a concatenation operator, not addition!

Comment: What's the larger problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Caleb: Excelent question, OP: why are you trying to implement such solution?

Answer (score 6):

Macros are not evaluated at runtime, the parameter you pass to a macro is used literally because "*it's not evaluated*". What you want to do is easily doable with arrays. Don't try to force the wrong approach when there is a simple and easy solution.

Since `a` is not evaluated, if you pass `a` then `a` is used hence

```
DEF(a)
```

is replaced with `DEFa`.

Do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int DEF[] = {[6] = 625};

int
main(void)
{
    int a = 6;
    printf("%d\n", DEF[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done.

Preprocessor replacement happens before the code is compiled. Variable `a` doesn't have any value at that point, it isn't even recognized as a variable or a type.

You will have to use a integer constant, or a define for that constant as you have shown in the first example.